# How would the hysteresis loop of a thin film be different than for a bulk material?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, material-science

I know that a hysteresis loop is characteristic of a material, that the width of the loop gives an indication about how permanent its magnetization is and that the area is related to the energy dissipated in the material per cycle.

I was wondering, however, how the hysteresis loop changes upon changing the dimensions of the material. Say you have a cobalt thin film, how does its hysteresis loop change when you make it thicker?